# Последовательную многопоточность сделать парралельной

Tags: java, многопоточность, future

Есть инструмент который использует многопоточность.

```
private class ReportCompiler implements Callable<List<String[]>> {
//конструктор, объявления переменых.

@Override
    public List<String[]> call() throws Exception {
        List<String[]> dadaOracle = new ArrayList<String[]>();
// логика обработки данных
return dadaOracle;
}
```

основной класс

```
class Main{
//...
//тут я заполняю мапу данными с помощью многопоточности
    Map<String, List<String[]>> resultMap = new HashMap<String, List<String[]>>();
for (String dsId : dc) {
        //...всякая логика
        ReportCompiler rc = new ReportCompiler(codesList, codesListAlco, assemblyParameters, list, listAlco);
        try {
            resultMap.put(dsId, rc.call());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

все отрабатывает хорош но медленно. думаю распараллеливание улучшит ситуацию.
подскажите пожалуйста как это распараллелить с помощью Future.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class TestThreadPool {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    Counter counter = new Counter();

    long start = System.nanoTime();

    double value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        value += counter.count(i);
    }

    System.out.printf("Executed by %d s, value : %f",
            (System.nanoTime() - start) / (1000_000_000),
            value);

        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        //MyThreadPool pool = new MyThreadPool(3);
        List<Future<Double>> list = new ArrayList();
        int j = 0;
        for (double i = 0.0; i < 100; i++, j++) {
            list.add(new FutureTask(new Counter(i)));
            pool.execute((Runnable)list.get(j));
        }
        Double result = 0.0 ;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                result += list.get(i).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestThreadPool.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestThreadPool.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        pool.shutdown();
                System.out.printf("time : %s s  result : %s", (System.nanoTime() - time) / (1000_000_000), result);


}


static class Counter implements Callable<Double>{

public Counter() {
}

    Double value = 0.0;
    public Counter(Double d) {
        value = d;
    }

public  Double count(double a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        a = a + Math.tan(a);
    }

    return a;
}

    @Override
    public Double call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return count(value);
    }
}
```

Вот как то раз реализовывал свой пул потоков, его уж скидывать не буду)
но вот как реализованный класс, который есть у всех, но смысл примерно один думаю сложности переделать под коллекцию стрингов не будет, я делал чисто чтоб понять как pool работает и поэтому просто каждый поток делает время затратную операцию, и потом главный поток собирает результаты.

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```